# Trying to access array offset on value of type null on VueJs when invoking Laravel Api

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am building a simple Laravel and VueJs project and I am encountering an unusual error when trying to register user. When i invoke an api endpoint on postman, the operation is successful and data is transformed to database when I am trying to do the same operation on VueJs UI, I am getting the error in the title. I understand the error and as a matter of fact, I encountered it before when testing on postman and was able to solve it but I cant seem to resolve it when getting from the UI.

Here is my code:

//function triggered when clicking submit[enter image description here][1]

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name:'Register',
    props:{
        message: String
    },
    data(){
        return{
            form: {
                name: '',
                email: '',
                password: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods:{
        submitForm(){
            axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/store', this.form)
                 .then( (response) =>{
                     console.log(response);
                     this.$router.push('/login');
                 })
                 .catch( (error) => {
                     console.log(error);
                 })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

//error I am getting
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYJ4Q.png

//but how could it be null when the data is passed in the request payload?
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW775.png

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

I ve tried composer update, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Does your api use the default laravel auth creation register? e.g. does it need `password_confirmation`

Comment: actually i think it does, I did more research and I found out that password needs some kind of confirmation. becuase now I keep getting :- The password confirmation does not match, any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, Add the `password_confirmation` to your form. otherwise if you want to ignore it just send through `password_confirmation` set to the default password. but id add it to the form.

Comment: Okay wow, laravel is kinda weird. Anyways, I added pass confirmation to my form, and updated the function, now it says password doesn't match